# Intermittent WARN ConsumerCoordinator We received an assignment that doesn't match our current subscription

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Why am I hitting the below WARN message intermittently when starting my Kafka Streams application?

Its more than a warning because it floods the application logs & the Kafka Streams app doesn't start.

Typically when I do a re-deploy it then works.

> `[my-app-0 my-app] 2020-03-25 14:00:12.931  WARN 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=my-app-b8f0b2a0-271b-4499-85bd-9e22d4a8b4b1-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-app] We received an assignment [topic-one-0, topic-two-0] that doesn't match our current subscription Subscribe(topic-two); it is likely that the subscription has changed since we joined the group. Will try re-join the group with current subscription`

After I restart the app the above WARN goes away & I get a different WARN, but at least the app works!

> `[my-app-0 my-app] 2020-03-25 14:05:54.300  WARN 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=my-app-b0f22dc1-479b-4f7c-a862-b20f70eedc35-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-app] The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members: [topic-one]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first message indicates that a consumer got a partition from a topic assigned that it did not subscribe to. This can happen if you spin up multiple application instances using the same `application.id` (and thus `group.id`) but both application subscribe to different topics: this is not allowed in Kafka Streams; all instances with the same `application.id` need to subscribe to the exact some topics and execute the exact same topology.

The second message indicates, that a consumer within a group did subscribe to a topic, but some topic partitions were not assigned to any consumer in the group. This can happen due to incremental rebalancing (as introduced in Kafka Streams 2.4): Before a topic partition is reassigned to a different client, it will first be only unassigned from the old client to allow the client to cleanup resources etc. In a consecutive rebalance the topic partition should be assigned to the new client. Hence, as long as the WARN does not persist (i.e., repeat over multiple rebalances) *and* a consecutive rebalance happens, it is expected behavior.